# QML: Move ScrollView to bottom when its height is changed?

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to make a message composer widget. I want to scroll to the bottom of the `ScrollView` when its height is changed so that the user can keep up with what they are writing. How can I achieve this sort of functionality?

**Here is my code for the `ScrollView` I am using:**

```
ScrollView {
        id: scrollView
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: clearTextBtn.left
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 0
        anchors.leftMargin: 0
        anchors.rightMargin: 10
        clip: true
        ScrollBar.horizontal.policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOff

        hoverEnabled: true

        onHoveredChanged: {
            if (hovered) {
                borderWidth = 2
                cursorShape = Qt.IBeamCursor

            } else {
                borderWidth = focus ? 2 : 0
                cursorShape = Qt.ArrowCursor
            }
        }

        onFocusChanged: {
            if (focus) {
                borderWidth = 2
            } else {
                borderWidth = 0
            }
        }

        TextEdit {
            id: textEdit
            width: scrollView.width
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignTop
            anchors.bottomMargin: 0
            anchors.topMargin: 0
            clip: true
            color: textColor
            anchors.left: parent.left
            wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
            anchors.leftMargin: 0
            padding: 10
            selectByMouse: true

            Label {
                id: placeholderTxt
                text: qsTr("Compose Message...")
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.top: parent.top
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignTop
                anchors.topMargin: 10
                anchors.rightMargin: 223
                anchors.leftMargin: 10
                visible: textEdit.length == 0 && !textEdit.activeFocus
                color: "#a3a3a3"
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    id: box
    width: 640
    height: 180
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("ScrollBar")

    Flickable {
        id: inputWrapper
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentHeight: input.implicitHeight
        contentWidth:  input.implicitWidth

        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            id: scrollBar
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
            anchors.left: box.right
        }
        Keys.onUpPressed: scrollBar.decrease()
        Keys.onDownPressed: scrollBar.increase()

        clip: true
        flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick
        function ensureVisible(r)
        {
            if (contentX >= r.x)
                contentX = r.x;
            else if (contentX+width <= r.x+r.width)
                contentX = r.x+r.width-width;
            if (contentY >= r.y)
                contentY = r.y;
            else if (contentY+height <= r.y+r.height)
                contentY = r.y+r.height-height;
        }
        TextEdit {
            id: input
            anchors.fill: parent
            text: ""
            focus: true
            wrapMode: TextEdit.Wrap
            onCursorRectangleChanged: inputWrapper.ensureVisible(cursorRectangle)


        }  // TextEdit
    }  // Flickable
}
```

[image]